# List with two main indices in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, indices

I have a function with three arguments (a matrix and two parameters) returning a list. I want to store the function values (here, list of matrices) for each `a` and `b` values so that I can extract a specific value from its indices.

A minimal example is below. (**not working but explaining the situation**)

How can I achieve this?

```
   ff <- function(X,a,b){
      ff1 <- a*X+b
      ff2 <- (a+b)*colSums(X)
      list(ff1,ff2)
    }

    X <- matrix(c(10,15,20,25),2)
    a <- c(1,2,3)
    b <- c(4,5,6,7)

    res <-  # ??????

    for(i in 1:length(a)){
      for(j in 1:length(b)){
        res[??????] <- ff(X,a[i],b[j])  # WRONG
      }
    }

    # WANT TO GET, for example
    res[2,3] # = ff(X,a=2,b=6)
```

Comment: How can `a` and `b` have different lengths? Or do you want to calculate `ff1` for all *combinations* of `a` and `b` values?

Comment: I want to calculate `ff1` and `ff2` for each `a[i]`, `b[j]` and combine them in a list `res[i,j]`. The result is `res` object. When I call `res[i,j]` (or sth like this), it should return `ff(X,a[j],b[j])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? This returns a `list` of `ff` return objects; every `list` entry corresponds to a particular `a`,`b` combination.

```
res <- apply(as.data.frame(expand.grid(a, b)), 1, function(w)
    ff(X, w[1], w[2]))
str(res)
#List of 12
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 14 19 24 29
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 125 225
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 24 34 44 54
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 150 270
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 34 49 64 79
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 175 315
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 15 20 25 30
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 150 270
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 25 35 45 55
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 175 315
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 35 50 65 80
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 200 360
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 16 21 26 31
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 175 315
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 26 36 46 56
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 200 360
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 36 51 66 81
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 225 405
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 17 22 27 32
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 200 360
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 27 37 47 57
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 225 405
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ : num [1:2, 1:2] 37 52 67 82
#  ..$ : num [1:2] 250 450
```

---

### Update

You *could* store the output of `ff` in a `tibble` where columns correspond to `a` and rows to `b` values. Every element is then a `list` which is the return object of `ff` for the particular `a`, `b` pair. IMO, this is a lot more unwieldy (and untidy) to work with but here you go:

```
library(tidyverse)
expand.grid(a, b) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(res = list(ff(X, Var1, Var2))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    spread(Var1, res)
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Var2 `1`        `2`        `3`
#  <dbl> <list>     <list>     <list>
#1    4. <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
#2    5. <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
#3    6. <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
#4    7. <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have a similar code too. The main part, I'm interested in is `call` phase. I need to call a specific result from its indices. For example,  `res[i,j]` or `res[[i,j]]` or sth. similar should return `ff[X,a[i],b[j]]`. So I can use this in the larger code I have.

Comment: There is only one main index in the list from `[[1]]` to `[[12]]` in the example above.. It should be in the form of `1,1; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 2,1; 2,2; 2,3 ....`

Comment: @mert I'd suggest rethinking your down-stream code design. Storing results in a `list` is a very convenient and R-conform approach, as it allows further processing of `res` using methods from the `*apply` family.  The key here is `expand.grid(a, b)` which stores all `a`, `b` combinations in a `data.frame`. Every row corresponds to a specific `a`, `b` combination, and for every row we calculate `ff(X, a, b)` and store its output in a `list` entry. In other words, the entries of `res` correspond to the rows of `expand.grid(a, b)`. That will allow you to select a specific `a`, `b` combination.

Comment: @mert *"There is only one main index in the list from `[[1]]` to `[[12]]` in the example above.. "* I have no idea what you mean. `ff` returns a `list` as by your design; we calculate `ff(X, a, b)` for different combinations `a`, `b`. So the output of `res` should be a `list` of `list`s. That's exactly the structure of my `res`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I could't explain myself. My idea is like matrix (or dataframe) with elements of lists. That is, `res` should be an object, which has two dimensions, with the elements of lists. But, if it is not possible, I will try to match the `res` with `expand.grid`'s output as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @mert I have added an update where I show how to store the output of `ff` in a 2d `tibble` where columns (rows) correspond to `a` (`b`) values. Please take look.

Comment: @ Maurits Evers It is okey now. Thank you.